# Flutter How to handle Firebase searchbox

Tags: firebase, flutter

I want to query by TextController from Firebase. It works when I work on `nickName` which it is "user52" or something like this in Firebase but when I try to query some complicated thing like adress, it doesn't work.

Snipped code part of my StreamBuilder:

```
StreamBuilder(
                    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                        .collection("users")
                        .where(
                          'adress',
                          isEqualTo: searchValue,
                        )
                        .snapshots(),
                    builder: (BuildContext context,
                        AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>
                            snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data != null) {
                        if (snapshot.data!.docs.isNotEmpty) {
                          return (snapshot.connectionState ==
                                  ConnectionState.waiting)
                              ? const Center(
                                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                )
                              : ListView.builder(
                                  itemCount: 1,
                                  itemBuilder:
                                      (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                    DocumentSnapshot data =
                                        snapshot.data!.docs[index];
                                    return InkWell(
                                      onTap: () {
                                       // 
                                      },
                                      child: ListTile(
                                        leading: const CircleAvatar(),
                                        title: Text(
                                          data['adress'],
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    );
                                  },
                                );
```

If there isn't an match this code will work (also this is part of streambuilder):

```
else {
                              
                              return const Center(
                                child: MyTxtWidget(
                                    text: "No match", size: 24),
                              );
                            }
```

I used  `isGreaterThanOrEquelTo`  instead of    `isEqualTo` but it is still not matching with complicated thing like `adress`.
I think this is about with Firebase. Query is working with one word field.
Also, I should mention that I can show the `adress` field with TextWidget in Firebase. There is nothing wrong with that.

Comment: Can you show what the structure looks like in Firebase? Is the address field a simple field or a complex structure?

Comment: It is just string like this "Sarkiye Mahallesi Düz Caddesi 250. sokak No 1 SAKARYA"

Comment: Yeah you're right, it may not match something like that unless it has been typed exactly as it is. You'll have to pull down the document references, loop through your documents, pull the address field and do a match doing like a case-insensitive string comparison or even a contains.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I'll think about this.